# Import SQL has been successfully, but it's error

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to import an sql to mysql databases, the warning says *"Import has been successfully finished, 15 queries executed. (inv-barang2.sql)"* but it also shows an error like below:

```
Error
SQL query: Copy


--
-- Database: `inv-barang2`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `admin`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

I was hoping that the sql can be imported successfully, and won't throw an error again.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to PHP? Did you select any database before running `CREATE TABLE`?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you didn't selected a db name before running the command, try this :

```
USE database_name;
```

or :

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```